# Microsoft Tag SoapFault exception

Tags: php, soap, tags

I'm attempting to create a category and tag through SOAP api (php) and keep getting an error on my dev server.  I've seen other people with this problem as well, I think it might be soap's fault? Categories create fine so not included, but here is the create tag info and the error

keep getting this error - can't figure out what is going on, categories work fine, just won't create a tag

```
<pre>
array(3) {
  ["userCredential"]=>
  object(UserCredential)#55 (1) {
    ["AccessToken"]=>
    string(36) "<myaccesstoken>"
  }
  ["categoryName"]=>
  string(13) "Site Group"
  ["tag"]=>
  object(URITag)#58 (8) {
    ["MedFiUrl"]=>
    string(32) "http://yoursite.com/c/17133"
    ["Title"]=>
    string(12) "qrcode_17133"
    ["InteractionNote"]=>
    NULL
    ["Status"]=>
    string(6) "Active"
    ["Types"]=>
    NULL
    ["UTCStartDate"]=>
    string(25) "2013-07-24T10:48:12-05:00"
    ["UTCEndDate"]=>
    NULL
    ["validTypes:private"]=>
    array(7) {
      [0]=>
      string(3) "pdf"
      [1]=>
      string(3) "wmf"
      [2]=>
      string(4) "jpeg"
      [3]=>
      string(3) "png"
      [4]=>
      string(3) "gif"
      [5]=>
      string(4) "tiff"
      [6]=>
      string(3) "tag"
    }
  }
}
</pre>
```

SoapFault exception: [a:InternalServiceFault] The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error.  For more information about the error, either turn on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute or from the  configuration behavior) on the server in order to send the exception information back to the client, or turn on tracing as per the Microsoft .NET Framework 3.0 SDK documentation and inspect the server trace logs.

i'm using soap, and have no idea how to turn on these server behavior settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was indeed a SOAP issue. The server is running php 5.1.6 and localhost (where it was working) is running 5.3+. I tracked down the SOAP request messages and noticed that the variable title of one item was not being sent via the server.

The solution is to extend the soap class with your own and rewrite the __doRequest method like follows:

```
class MySoap extends SoapClient{

  public function __doRequest( $request ,  $location ,  $action ,  $version ,  $one_way = 0 ){
    $request = preg_replace('/<ns1:tag>/', '<ns1:tag xsi:type="ns1:URITag">', $request);
    $ret = parent::__doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version);
    $this->__last_request = $request;
    return $ret;
  }
}
```